# Extending Textbox.Text to add "\n"

Tags: textbox

I haven't come up with a clever way of making TextBox.Text work exactly the way it currently does, but at the end always put a + "\n" at the end of it.  The best I have done is make many overloaded functions like:

```
prtMain(string s) {  tbMain.Text += s + "\n"; }
prtMain(string s1, string s2) { tbMain.Text += s1 + " " + s2 + "\n";}
```

I'm guessing there is a clever way to add to the existing .text code but not sure how.

[Edit] in c# to answer a question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm answering my own question.  It looks like what I want is an Extension method.  This is what I did:

```
static class Util
{
    public static int MyText(this TextBox txtBox, string s)
    {
        txtBox.Text += s + "\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So I can call this by using tbMyTextBox.MyText("Hello");  Next step, get to where I can say tbMyTextBox.MyText = Hello.